# How to trigger on bound item in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, triggers

I want to activate a trigger if the bound items property ID is equal to a property in my custom control.

But i can't use bindings in my triggers!

How would i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<DataTrigger
    Value="True">

    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding
            Converter="{x:Static local:EqualityConverter.Instance}">
            <Binding
                Path="BoundProperty" />
            <Binding
                ElementName="MockCustomControl"
                Path="Text" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>

    <DataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter
            TargetName=" ... "
            Property=" ... "
            Value=" ... " />

         ...
         ...

    </DataTrigger.Setters>

</DataTrigger>
```

And the converter may be something similar to this:

```
public class EqualityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public static readonly EqualityConverter Instance = new EqualityConverter();

    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length == 0) return false;

        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
            if (!values[i].Equals(values[0])) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note that I've used a generic convrter that can campare n values, but you can use a simple one as per your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I Always get values[1] set to DependencyProperty.UnsetValue on the binding to the property. I have tried many variations but always get UnsetValue! Suggestions?

Comment: on my side, it's working perfectly! It seems that there's some issue with your bindings. Where's your control (which i've named `MockCustomControl`) situated in visual tree? May be you can upload your project somewhere (like http://SkyDrive.com) so that I can help you further :)

Comment: Shorter implementation would be:
return values != null && values.Length >= 1 && values.Skip(1).All(v => v == values[0]);

Answer (score 0):

DataTrigger's value property doesn't take bindings?

```
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BoundPropertyId}" Value="{Binding ElementName=Mine, Path=Property}" />
```

If that doesn't work, you might need to hook onto an event and process it yourself in the code-behind.

Comment: I can't use binding in the Value-tag

Comment: You can't set Binding on Value because it isn't a DependencyProperty. However, as @apandit said, DataTrigger is what you are looking for!